# Paid components for Android

Tags: android, components

are there any paid components (pre-prepared items for use in business applications) for Android, like some special ListView, app-navigation solution, tab panels and so on? I have found only a few of free components, but I'd like to see paid solutions. Do you know about anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resco has a new Android Edition, I only used they WindowsMobile Toolkit, that was great.
[resco.net](http://www.resco.net/developer/mobileformstoolkit/overview.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I see Resco components for android aren't available for sell now... something about mono droid licencing. Do you know about any others, which are available?